# Unable to sync app_commands into bot command tree

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I am trying to organize my code by putting the command code of discord commands into separate cogs files but I am unable to sync application commands into the bot. Each time, the normal commands.Context commands sync properly but the discord.Interaction commands does not sync. How can I solve this problem? I watched multiple tutorials, but nothing seems to work. Could I get to know how people do it in 2023?

**./cogs/stats.py:**

```
class cmds(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client: commands.Bot):
        self.client = client

   
    @app_commands.command(name='stats', description='Get stats of anything from the website')
    @app_commands.describe(type="Which thing do you want stats for?")
    @app_commands.describe(query='What do you want search for?')
    async def stats(self, ctx: discord.Interaction, type: int, query: str):
        try:
            if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.DMChannel):
                await ctx.response.send_message("Please use this command in a discord server instead!")
                return

            if type == 1:

                guild_ng = f'https://api.ngmc.co/v1/guilds/{query}'
                header = {
                'Authorization': API_KEY,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
                response_from_API_guild = requests.get(headers=header, url=guild_ng)
                response_from_API_guild.raise_for_status()

                response_g = response_from_API_guild.json()


              
                members = "\n• " + "\n• ".join([f"[{member}](<https://ngmc.co/p/{member}>)" for member in response_g["members"]])
                logger.info(members)
                logger.info(str(len(members)))
                officers = "\n• " + "\n• ".join(response_g["officers"])
                officers_count = len(response_g['officers'])

                embed_g = discord.Embed(
                    title=response_g['name'],
                    description=f"Guild MOTD: **{response_g['motd']}**",
                    color=discord.Color.brand_green()
                )
                 ...
          if type == 2:
               #more embeds and stuff...

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(cmds(client))
```

**main.py:**

```
class CustomClient(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='_', intents=discord.Intents.all())

    async def setup_hook(self):
        await bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=1148546198219788308))
        logger.info('Done')

bot = CustomClient()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
            
            logger.info("Loaded")
```

Could I know what's wrong?

I was expecting to see that the command is successfully synced to the bot's command tree but it does not even tho no errors or problems are shown/printed in the console